# Como utilizar o mesmo menu Drawer Navigation em várias Activitys sem repetir código?

Tags: java, android

Como utilizar o mesmo menu **drawer** Navigation em várias **activitys** sem repetir código?

Comment: Utilize o `container` como um `FrameLayout`

Comment: de uma olhada nesse código: https://gist.github.com/anandbose/7d6efb35c900eaba3b26

Answer (score 1):

É possível usar uma Activity apenas, e injetar fragmentos no container, assim ficaria só com um menu (porém eu não recomendo, mas fica a seu critério)

Answer (score 0):

Coloque todo o código de inicializar o drawer dentro de uma activity(DrawerNavigatableActivity extends Activity) e faça todas as suas activities que precisarem desse comportamento herdarem dela.